# Why doesn't this change the framenumber?

Tags: equations, alignment

Here is a piece of code that some friend wrote, but I cannot remember the name. It actually allows the line break to maintain the actual vertical line of the equality signs of the displayed equations. However, it does not, obviously, increment the frame number. Also, it won't work inside a frame, where the frame number would be automatically taken care of. 2 questions.

**(1)** Why doesn't it work inside a frame?

**(2)** why can't I change the frame number outside a frame with `addtocounter{framenumber}{1}`?

This is a continuation to my previous message up here, which unfortunately, wasn't completely answered.

```
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= e^{\int 1dx}\left(C+\int e^{\int(-1)dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^{\int dx}\left(C+\int e^{-\int dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x\left(C+\int e^{-x}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x(C+x).
\end{align*}
\endgroup
```

The lines move on to the next page after the first one. However, the equality signs on the second page are exactly aligned to those on the previous page.
Thank you!
latexatha

Here is a full page of what I mean.

```
\documentclass[11pt,compress,pdf,leqno,article]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetheme{Madrid}                               

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{} % added march 13, 2020
%
\newcommand{\blo}{Hi!\\}
%
\begin{document}
\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= e^{\int 1dx}\left(C+\int e^{\int(-1)dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^{\int dx}\left(C+\int e^{-\int dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x\left(C+\int e^{-x}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x(C+x).
\end{align*}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Thank you all!!!

Comment: Please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question. Which document class do you use? From the word "frame", I guess, you use `beamer`. Is that correct?

Comment: Try deleting the spurious `}` character before `\endgroup` and interchanging the order of `\endgroup` and `\end{align*}`?

Comment: Mico, Sorry about that. There is no such character. That came from a macro of mine. It doesn't work without it either. Thank you!

Comment: leandriis, I am using \documentclass[11pt,compress,pdf,leqno,article]{beamer} Thank you.

Comment: leandriis, I just place the equations at the end of the page so that they don't all fit. Just let a couple of them go on to the next page and see the result, You can do it inside the frame, to see that the code doesn't work, or outside a frame where the code works, but I cannot increment the frame number. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the documentclass et al into the question, so that we have something we can copy and paste and see what you're talking about.  Put enough text so that a couple of them go to the next page and we can see the result.  Please also link to your previous question, so that we can easily find it.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your problems. Putting it in standard beamer documentation works as expected, however if you not add to preamble  a `\theme`, which provide frame numbering, then frame are not numbered. Testing with for example `\usetheme{Madrid}` numbering also works as expected.

Comment: @Zarko 
I have included the full code for an example. Thank you! latexatha

Comment: @Teepeemm, I have included the full code for an example. Thank you! latexatha

Comment: You say you wish to increment and display frame numbers, but your test document doesn't contain `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` statements. If I insert them in the appropriate places in the test document and delete the `\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo` instruction (you're not serious about it, are you?), the frame is numbered correctly (`1/1`) and the four-row `align*` environment looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `beamer` document class is intended for preparation of presentations. They are consist from frames, however in your document example they are not present.

If they are included in your document as it shown in the following MWE regarding frame numbering:

```
\documentclass[11pt,compress,pdf,leqno,article]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%
\newcommand{\blo}{Hi!\\}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo\blo
\begingroup
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= e^{\int 1dx}\left(C+\int e^{\int(-1)dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^{\int dx}\left(C+\int e^{-\int dx}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x\left(C+\int e^{-x}e^xdx\right)\\
&=e^x(C+x).
\end{align*}
\endgroup
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

than you will get after (at least) two compilation desired/correct result:

[image]

**Edit:**
In my opinion, the result of your presentation is not beautiful, in fact it doesn't allow listeners to follow the derivation present in your equations' system. It would be better to write equations in own frame:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%% modification of the \exp                                   %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\makeatletter
\let\origexp\exp
\DeclareRobustCommand{\exp}{\@ifnextchar^{\Exp^{}}{\origexp }}
\def\Exp^#1{\,\mathop{\mathrm{\mathstrut e}\!\!}\nolimits^{#1}\,}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dx}{\,\mathrm{d}x}

\newcommand{\blo}{Hi!\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Test of multi slide frame}
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
\item   Hi!
    \end{itemize}

\begin{align*}
y(x)& = \exp^{\int 1\dx}\left(C+\int \exp^{\int(-1) \dx}\exp^{x} \dx\right)\\
    & = \exp^{\int \dx}\left(C +\int \exp^{-\int \dx}\exp^{x} \dx\right)\\
    & = \exp^{x} \left(C+\int \exp^{-x}\exp^x \dx\right)\\
    & = \exp^{x}(C+x).
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

IN above MWE are also introduced some changes in writing equations which (according to my opinion) enables easier distinction between variables and math operators and constants.

[image]

Comment: that's just great! Just a little proble though, there is a big space between the
first display on the second page and the top of the page. How do I reduce that vertical space?
Thank you again! latexatha

Comment: @latexatha, about adding spaces,  there is not much to do. BTW, I would not present your presentation matter on such a way. To my original answer I added an example of presentation that looks better (at least in my opinion).